# Lookback 2.0 and Lumenize example

Tags: rally, lookbackapi, lumenize

API 2.0 RC1.  I can call the lookback snapshot store to return the records I want, but then I can't get the calculator to work correctly.  The Lumenize functions are undefined: TypeError: Rally.data.lookback.Lumenize is undefined

I run the query, works as expected.  But then, how do I "Lumenize", i.e. consolidate to granularity of a day, and generate the correct summary output? The following does not work, and all of the examples are pre-2.0RC1.

```
//works to get the raw data
Ext.create('Rally.data.lookback.SnapshotStore', {
    filters: [
        {
            property: '_TypeHierarchy',
            operator: 'in',
            value: ['Defect', 'HierarchicalRequirement']
        },
        {
            property: 'Iteration',
            operator: 'in',
            value: iteration
        },
        {
            property: '_ValidFrom',
            operator: '>=',
            value: this.startDate
        }
    ],
    autoLoad: true,
    fetch: ['Name','FormattedID','ScheduleState','PlanEstimate','Iteration','Release','Project'],
    listeners: {
        load: {
            fn: this._onDataLoaded,
            scope: this
        }
    }
});

//Lumenize not working
_onDataLoaded: function(store, data) {
    var config = {
        startOn: this.startDate,
        endBefore: this.endDate,
        tz: 'America/Denver',
        workDays:'Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday',
        granularity: 'day',
        metrics: {"field": "PlanEstimate"},
        summaryMetricsConfig: [
            {
                "field": "PlanEstimate",
                "as": "Planned",
                "display": "line",
                "f": "sum"
            },
            {
                "field": "PlanEstimate",
                "as": "Completed",
                "f": "filteredSum",
                "filterField": "ScheduleState",
                "filterValues": "Accepted",
                "display": "column"
            }
        ]                   
    };

    var calculator = new Rally.data.lookback.Lumenize.TimeSeriesCalculator(config);
    var myData = calculator.prepareChartData(store);
    var mySummary = calculator.getResults();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately due to the size of the sdk.js bundle, it was decided not to package the lumenize libs therein. There's an analytics-all.js lib that contains Lumenize, however it doesn't get loaded unless you instantiate a Rally.ui.chart.Chart component.

The easiest thing to do is to explicitly include analytics-all.js *after* sdk.js:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/2.0rc1/sdk.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/2.0rc1/lib/analytics/analytics-all.js"></script>
```

Comment: I get a 404 error "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc1/lib/analytics/analtycis-all.js"

Comment: Sorry, the script tag in the answer had a typo. It's been fixed.